# How i can display my subscription form in web browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I am facing a problem with my code. I want to create a subscribe form modal. I have added subscribe form in my HTML document but when I run code into the browser I do not see subscribe portion there, What is the problem? Please help

Here is my code link:

https://github.com/Nourin-020/Coming_soon

Comment: Stack overflow is set to share your code within it. I would ask you to place your code below your question not a third party website.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it seems that you forgot to hook up the `<button>` to the modal form.

```
<button class="btn" id="subscribe-modal-open">Subscribe</button>
```

Likely requires some `data-` arguments. I suspect something like this should do:

```
<button class="btn" id="subscribe-modal-open" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#subscribe-modal">Subscribe</button>
```

---

Next, you'll want to delete this entire section from your `style.css`. Almost every line in this block is a problem (the `z-index`, the `width`, the `top`/`left`, the `background`; none of these work as you likely desired, when combined with the bootstrap modal stuff)

```
#subscribe-modal{
    text-align: center;;
    width:100%;
    color:#fff;
    background:red;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000; 
}
```

---

And finally, you've broken a bunch of things in the bootstrap dialog html that you started with (probably while trying to diagnose your problem). A few tags were missing and you were using some bootstrap `class`names as `id`. I'd suggest just updating the bit between your `<!-- Subscribe Model -->` comments with:

```
  <!-- Subscribe Model -->
    <div id="subscribe-modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h2 class="modal-title">Subscribe Our Channel</h2>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            <form>
              <input type="email" name="email" id="">
              <input type="submit" value="Submit now">
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <!-- Subscribe Model -->
```

I've cloned your github and tested it, and this fixes the problems.

Comment: Okay but my main problem is the result is not showing my browser. I have added red background in subscriber section to find out .But i can't see any red box when i run the code.

Comment: I've updated my answer above with the other changes that were required.